# Display Bootstrap's hamburger menu by default and place it on the left side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How might I display Bootstrap's collapsed, aka "Hamburger", menu by default but to have it on the left side of the browser?

I'm guessing that on the collapsed menu, I just change it to be as below?

```
<!-- the collapsing menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Comment: `Hamburger?` okay back to the on hand question, what do you want left? text, the button?

Comment: @Dorvalla that name is ubiquitous across the web. And I'm assuming the whole menu left.

Comment: Yea, i prefer not to call it hamburger, its so .. offensive ... against those 3 nice lines, perfectly placed... i dont see a bun in it .. or is that the button ... hehehe. Still its not entirely clear what you wish. You want it left alligned.. or the whole menu on the left side of your screen, when you click it? If the last one is the case, check this link. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus

Comment: The menu that shows the three lines on mobile, but also need to position it on the left side. I'm developing a site that just wants to use the collapsed menu on all devices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to create a navbar with a three line "hamburger" on mobile devices, just follow the official [Bootstrap template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/). If you want to move the button to the left, just add a float: left to the css or use the class "pull-left" on the button. Do note that you will need to add some margin: left to make sure there's some spacing between the button and the left border.

[Bootply example here](http://www.bootply.com/o3FgwBWTd4)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to have it be the default menu? I don't want the list items populate the menu bar when users are on large screens. I'd like to have the "hamburger" present the whole time.

Comment: The most straightforward way to achieve that is by manipulating the less files and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

- as martin mentioned you need a pull-left attribute for the hamburger to be on the left
- with the code below the left hamburger only shows up when the screen is too small to show all the nav bar items

> ```
> nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">   <div class="container-fluid">
>     <div class="navbar-header">
>       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
>       </button>
>       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Slide Show</a>
>     </div>
>     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
>       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>         <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
>         <li><a href="/shutdown">Shutdown</a></li> 
>         <li><a href="/about">About</a></li> 
>       </ul>
>       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
>         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
>       </ul>
>     </div>   </div> </nav>
> ```